# AWS Access denied putobject php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to upload file on `AWS s3`. but getting access denied error.

Here is my code

```
$result = $this->Amazon->S3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'               => 'mycustom.testing',
    'Signature'            => 'v4',
    'ACL'                  => 'public-read',
    'Key'                  => $key,
    'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256',
    'SourceFile'           => $tmp,
    'Body'                 => $tmp,
    'CacheControl'         => 'max-age=172800',
    'debug'                => true
    // 'ContentType'       => $_FILES['data']['type']['User']['image'],
));
```

and my bucket policy is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests referred by www.myweb.co and myweb.co",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mycustom.testing/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://www.myweb.co/*",
                        "http://myweb.co/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": ["s3:PutObject"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mycustom.testing/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If I remove  `'ACL' => 'public-read',` then file will upload but then I am not able to see it by url. I try to add `s3:PutObjectAcl` in action but then bucket policy error shown and I am not able to save policy.

Comment: You probably need to generate a pre-signed url when you want to access the files in the bucket https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-url.html.